# 'swipl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: prolog, system-variable

I already added the path to my system variables but still when I type swipl in the command prompt it doesn't open the program.
[System Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xw2v6.png)

Comment: You need to add "D:\swipl\bin" to the end of "Path"

Comment: Of interest: [Install SWI-Prolog development version on Windows 10](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/install-swi-prolog-development-version-on-windows-10/1131)

Comment: @DavidTonhofer did that and it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you add the path of SWIPL which is mostly found at "C:\Program Files\swipl\bin" (unless specified explicitly) to your System Variable - PATH. Then reopen you command prompt and try again.